# Why doesn't Total Sum of Squares change when we add up new variable to a regression equation?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, econometrics

I understand the reason for RSS to change, but how about TSS? 
Is it somehow associated with the constant number of observations?

Comment: TSS is total deviation from slope of regression line so, if it changes, you're TSS will change.

Comment: @mlofton No, that's the residual sum of squares. The total sum of squares $\sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2$  is proportional to the variance of your left hand side variable $y$ and doesn't depend on your right hand side variables.

Comment: sorry Matthew. the average of y. my bad and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @MatthewGunn commented the Total Sum of Squares (TSS) is a characteristic of the outcome (y) variable.

The calculation of the TSS is a step in the way to calculate the variance (variance = TSS/ n-1) of the y variable. As such it is independent of the influence of the predictors (x).

In the regression the TTS will be divided into the Model Sum of Squares (MSS) and the Residual Sum of Squares (RSS). The addition of a predictor will only alter the proportion of the MSS to the RSS. But when the MSS and the RSS are summed together they will always result in the TSS.

This is the rationale behiind the R². It can only be interpreted as a percentage because it is the MSS (the proportion explained by the model) divided by the (non-changing) TSS.